# Explicit conversion of JToken to string with false "possible null reference return" warning

Tags: c#, json.net, nullable-reference-types

I'm using C#10, Newtonsoft.Json and nullable reference types. I made a simple wrapper around JObject:

```
public class JsonWrapper
{
    readonly JObject j;
    public JsonWrapper(string json)
    {  
        j = JObject.Parse(json);
    }

    public string SelectTokenAsString(string jsonPath)
    {
        // 1st warning: Possible null reference return
        // 2nd warning: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable 
        return (string)SelectToken(jsonPath);
    }

    public int SelectTokenAsInt(string jsonPath)
    {
        return (int)SelectToken(jsonPath);
    }

    JToken SelectToken(string jsonPath)
    {
        if (jsonPath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jsonPath));
        JToken? result = j.SelectToken(jsonPath);
        if (result == null) throw new MyException("Bla-bla-bla");
        return result;
    }
}
```

As you can see I put comments in `SelectTokenAsString` method. Why Visual Studio underline this row with green wiggily line and thinks there are possible null reference return and possible conversion to null? It's pretty clear that SelectToken method is never return null. Interestingly that VS thinks that `SelectTokenAsInt` method is totally ok which it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting `JToken` to `string` actually returns `string?` ([see `public static explicit operator string?(JToken? value)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/c9e12bc4755c786a9073dddf1be14cd27823a498/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L1235)). So warning is raised about the result of casting `JToken` to `string` not the result of `SelectToken` (I assume the reason for such behaviour can be handling of `null` json token).

You can try using `JToken.ToString` overload (which internally calls `JToken.ToString(Formatting.Indented)` so potentially it can give not the result you expect):

```cs
public string SelectTokenAsString(string jsonPath) => SelectToken(jsonPath).ToString();
```

Comment: do `explicit operator string?(JToken? value)` is the same as `explicit operator string(JToken? value)` (the second one has the string without a question mark). I mean I'm casting to (string) not to (string?)

Comment: @MaxJacobi: Due to the way C# handles nullable reference types, there's not really a difference between those two operator signatures, except for some special attributes that get added to the method metadata to help with nullable checking.

Comment: @MaxJacobi [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) are not actually separate types (as nullable value types), they are used only for static flow analysis (you can view this as some kind of type erasure by compiler), i.e. nullability is not used as part method signature during overload resolution (you can't declare `void Do(string s)` and `void Do(string? s)` in one class) etc., so yes, basically both operators are the same.

Comment: @GuruStron I checked your link to github and find out that they use that kind of overload [operator int(JToken value)](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/c9e12bc4755c786a9073dddf1be14cd27823a498/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L746) vs [operator int?(JToken? value)](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/c9e12bc4755c786a9073dddf1be14cd27823a498/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L887) that's odd because I tested it on a console project and VS doesn't allow me to overload `explicit operator string(Program value)` with `explicit operator string?(Program? value)`.

Comment: Oh, wait. It allow to overload nullable value types...

Comment: @MaxJacobi sorry for bad wording - "as nullable value types" in my comment means that nullable value types are actually separate types in C# ([`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-6.0)) so `int?` is actually `Nullable<int>` and is different type from `int` and you can overload based on value type nullability.

Answer (score 1):

Guru Stron's answer is correct, but I wanted to provide a little more explanation.

If you break your code down a little further, here's what's happening on that line:

```
    JToken token = SelectToken(jsonPath); // no warning
    return (string)token!; // warning
```

So even though your `SelectToken` method doesn't return a nullable type, the conversion of that JToken into a `string` *might* return a null value, due to the implicit operator that performs that conversion. Remember that `null` is a valid JSON token, so the following code would give you a `null` value, even though your check to ensure the `JToken?` isn't null passes and doesn't throw an exception.

```
string? foo = new JsonWrapper(@"{""foo"": null}").SelectTokenAsString("foo");
```

You're probably better off doing one more null check to make sure you don't end up with a null string like this:

```
    JToken token = SelectToken(jsonPath);
    return (string?)token ?? throw new InvalidCastException($"Token value at path {jsonPath} was null");
```